# Fill an array with a random permutation

Tags: java, arrays, random

So I'm a little stuck on this one. I have been trying and searching for hours and I've yet to find a solution that fits within my professors very strict parameters.

I have to fill an array with a random permutation of numbers from 0-9, and they can't repeat. I'm aware that there are a lot of topics on this and I've found a few ways to do it, but it doesn't fit within our requirements.

So I have to use a regular array and a Random object with a given seed to fill an array with unique values. I can't use collections, ArrayLists, any sort of iterator, just regular loops. I can't even create another class to do the function.
My basic idea so far

```
    for(int i=1; i<numItems; i++)
    {
        int count = 1;
        int m=rand.nextInt(numItems);
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            if(m==permutation[j])
            {
                m=rand.nextInt(numItems);
                count++;
                j=-1;
            }
        } 
        permutation[i]=m;
        numAttempts[i]=count;    
    }
```

And this works perfectly, but we can't modify the control variable (j) inside of the loop.

I basically want it to start testing from the beginning with the random numbers that the rand object is generating any time that if statement is true.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: His output [image]

Comment: Simplest solution is to fill the array with unique values (easy) and then do a fair shuffle of its contents. That avoids having to keep track of which values have/haven't already been seen, since it starts unique and is demonstrably still unique after each shuffle step.

Comment: I can't shuffle them. It has to be consistent output and it has to look exactly like his, which doesn't use shuffle.

Comment: What do you mean it has to look exactly like his? Shuffling with the same random seed will be consistent.

Comment: Sorry, I added what his output looks like, it's a better representation of what I mean.

Comment: @keshlam I'm modifying j inside the loop to cause it to start the loop over again anytime that the next pseudorandom number matches any of the other elements in the array.

Comment: What is `s`? What is `m`? What are `numAttempts`, `maxNumAttempts[]` and the other arrays? You have left out half the question. You also still do not mention the no-shuffle requirement in your question, and perhaps don't mention other things. I find it hard to believe that your professor did not clearly indicate to you what is and is not allowed.

Comment: ... Right. This is a particularly horrible approach to the stated problem, though. (But his example output doesn't seem to match your description of the problem, so maybe I'm missing something.)

Comment: Come on, why would I make this more complicated for myself than it has to be?

I didn't include those because I know how to do those. I want to know how to make it look exactly like his output using a Random object. My code does that, but I can't modify a control variable inside of a loop according to him. He told us in class we can do it with nothing but arrays and loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking at the required output, your algorithm should be:

> For every number i, pick random numbers until you get one you didn't already pick. Then put that number in the array and record how many numbers you had to pick before you got a new one.

So, refactoring your code a little bit to use a loop instead of resetting `j` to -1:

```
for(int i=1; i<numItems; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool found = false;
    do {
        int m=rand.nextInt(numItems);
        count++;
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            if(m==permutation[j])
            {                   
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        } 
    } while (found);
    permutation[i]=m;
    numAttempts[i]=count;    
}
```

(My java is rusty, that syntax could be wrong, but I hope you get the idea)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I think! A do-while loop, I couldn't wrap my head around it before.

Comment: I think you meant `while(!found)`. Other than that... yeah, that seems to be what he was asking for. I still say it's a horrible solution for the stated problem, but if the goal is to demonstrate that as the table fills up it becomes progressively harder to find a value which hasn't already been used (perhaps to illustrate the statistics and demonstrate why this *is* a horrible solution), it does accomplish that.

Comment: @keshlam no arguments from me! But the professor has a very unorthodox approach.

Comment: @keshlam `while (found)` is right, it loops while the random number was found in the list of picked numbers. Agree the solution is nasty, both performance and readability wise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the algorithm used in the example is:

```
1. Draw number from PRNG
2. Scan every previous entry in array to check if value is present
3. If yes, go to 1
4. Assign number to this entry
5. Proceed to next entry
6. Go to 1
```

`numAttempts` appears to be the number of re-draws that had to be made for every entry. You can optimize his implementation substantially by not drawing the last entry randomly, and instead just exploiting the fact that after `n-1` entries are assigned, there is only one possibility for the `n`th one.

Comment: I can't shuffle, check his output.

Comment: @user3092589 Please rewrite your question to clearly state all the requirements.

Comment: I edited my post to add the requirements, my question remains the same. There is quite a lot we can't do, so it was hard to remember them all.